# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed theme is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Before I start the question, I am new in JavaScript, and I have very basic knowledge of async js, but i need to solve this so i can have my first project functional.

I am trying to build a scraping app using Node and Puppeteer. Basically, the user enters a URL ("link" in the code below), puppeteer goes trough the website code, tries to find the specific piece and returns the data. That part I got working so far.

The problem is when a user enters a URL of a site that doesn't have that piece of code. In that case, I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed theme is not defined`

What do I do so when there is an error like that, I can catch it and redirect the page instead of Getting Internal Server error.

```
app.post("/results", function(req, res) {
  var link = req.body.link;
  (async link => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    const data = await page.evaluate('theme.name');
    await browser.close()
    return data
  })(link)
  .then(data => {
    res.render("index", {data: data, siteUrl: link});
  })
})
```

Comment: In the case of Primise, you always have .`catch()` to handle the errors. but when you use 'await` you should always use `try { ... } catch(e) {...}`  wrapping `await statement`. so that you can catch potential errors

Comment: I definitely need more time to learn all those things. I only started learning Web Development a month ago. It will be a long way ahead. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the async part to the whole route handler and do whatever you want on catch:

```
app.post('/results', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const link = req.body.link
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    const data = await page.evaluate('theme.name')
    await browser.close()
    res.render("index", {data: data, siteUrl: link})
  } catch(e) {
    // redirect or whatever
    res.redirect('/')
  }
});
```

Comment: @jugoslav-spasevski Oh Common'. Thats what i said, wrap statements in `try catch` block

Comment: @JimishFotariya I did say thank you to you too :) Nino's answer was just easier to Copy/Paste. And having only a month of experience in WebDev, and zero knowledge of Async, it was easier to test it. It doesn't mean I do not appreciate your answer. On the contrary, I am very thankful the community here is so amazing! Once again, thank you :)